# One route from nested routes not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have a User model which has_many :portfolios and each Portfolio has_many :pictures.  My routes look like this:

```
resources :users do
  resources :portfolios do
    resources :pictures
  end
end
```

Then I try to create a new Portfolio like this:

```
<%= link_to "new portfolio...", new_user_portfolio_path(current_user) %>
```

With a form like this:

```
<%= form_for [current_user, @portfolio], html: { class: "form_settings" } do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

But when I click on "new portfolio..."  my URL says `/users/12/portfolios/new` and I get this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"portfolios", :user_id=>#<User id: 12, name: "michael", password_digest: "d787f56b080945c1ec0b3343cbf962ca427bb8ef", remember_token: "dL4nPlt0E5azUMemNIvkdg", admin: false, created_at: "2013-03-03 01:18:19", updated_at: "2013-03-03 19:56:28">, :id=>#<Portfolio id: nil, user_id: 12, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}
```

Comment: Can you plz try <%= link_to "new portfolio...", new_user_portfolio_path(:user_id => current_user.id) %>

Comment: That doesn't work. I don't understand this. When I run rake routes I get `new_user_portfolio GET /users/:user_id/portfolios/new(.:format)` which is exactly the format of my URL with the error on the page. om, does it matter what URL I'm coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the error is coming from the form to create the portfolio. There must be a link on the `/portfolios/new` page to add a picture or something like that, and this is what's failing (because the portfolio is a new record).

You need to hide this link when you're on the `new` page.

Comment: that's it. It's my layout file. I have a menu toolbar which looks like this: 
<% current_user.portfolios.each do |portfolio| %>
<li><%= link_to portfolio.name, user_portfolio_path(current_user, portfolio) %></li>
<% end %>
<li><%= link_to "new portfolio...", new_user_portfolio_path(current_user) %></li>
It works when I'm at `/users/12` but when I try to go to `/users/12/portfolios/new` it breaks.  So my question is, how can I link to the `show` page of each portfolio from the `new` page?

Comment: Start with `link_to portfolio.name, user_portfolio_path(current_user, portfolio) unless portfolio.new_record?`, but the failing link is trying to hit the pictures controller, so I don't think it's your error. When you look at the logs, what's the line raising the exception?

Comment: ok, that fixed it. My error was wrong because instead of using `user_portfolio_path` I was using `user_portfolio_picture_path`.  But I don't understand why your solution works...thanks, btw.

Comment: It's because you built a porfolio on the user, but this portfolio is a new record, so it doesnt have an id yet. Without id, `user_portfolio_path(current_user, portfolio)` can't build the url. You should accept the answer if it fixed it ;)